# WLAN Access Point (bridge) freeze at "nl80211: Set beacon"

Tags: wifi

I recently tried to setp up a WiFi Hotspot with my RaspberryPi with `hostapd` as wifi to eth0 bridge.

When i try to debug **hostapd** `hostapd -d /etc/hostapdhostapd.conf`i get the following messages:

```
ctrl_interface_group=0
nl80211: interface wlan0 in phy phy0
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 4
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 3
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Create interface iftype 6 (MONITOR)
nl80211: New interface mon.wlan0 created: ifindex=5
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 5
nl80211: Adding interface wlan0 into bridge br0
BSS count 1, BSSID mask 00:00:00:00:00:00 (0 bits)
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=00
nl80211: 2402-2472 @ 40 MHz
nl80211: 2457-2482 @ 40 MHz
nl80211: 2474-2494 @ 20 MHz
nl80211: 5170-5250 @ 160 MHz
nl80211: 5250-5330 @ 160 MHz
nl80211: 5490-5730 @ 160 MHz
nl80211: 5735-5835 @ 80 MHz
nl80211: 57240-63720 @ 2160 MHz
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Completing interface initialization
Mode: IEEE 802.11g  Channel: 1  Frequency: 2412 MHz
nl80211: Set freq 2412 (ht_enabled=1 sec_channel_offset=0)
Failed to update rate sets in kernel module
RATE[0] rate=10 flags=0x1
RATE[1] rate=20 flags=0x1
RATE[2] rate=55 flags=0x1
RATE[3] rate=110 flags=0x1
RATE[4] rate=60 flags=0x0
RATE[5] rate=90 flags=0x0
RATE[6] rate=120 flags=0x0
RATE[7] rate=180 flags=0x0
RATE[8] rate=240 flags=0x0
RATE[9] rate=360 flags=0x0
RATE[10] rate=480 flags=0x0
RATE[11] rate=540 flags=0x0
Flushing old station entries
Deauthenticate all stations
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr 00:87:40:71:c2:a0 and ssid 'ComplicatedPi'
Deriving WPA PSK based on passphrase
SSID - hexdump_ascii(len=13):
     43 6f 6d 70 6c 69 63 61 74 65 64 50 69            ComplicatedPi
PSK (ASCII passphrase) - hexdump_ascii(len=9): [REMOVED]
PSK (from passphrase) - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
random: Got 20/20 bytes from /dev/random
Get randomness: len=32 entropy=0
GMK - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
Get randomness: len=32 entropy=0
Key Counter - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
WPA: Delay group state machine start until Beacon frames have been configured
RSN pre-auth interface 'wlan0'
VLAN: vlan_set_name_type(name_type=2)
nl80211: Set beacon (beacon_set=0)
```

After **`nl80211: Set beacon (beacon_set=0)`** the command line freezes and i have to unplug my WiFi Stick or reboot the RPi manually.

Another error: **`Failed to update rate sets in kernel module`**

[This](https://www.amazon.de/The-Hut-USB-WLAN-Adapter-f%C3%BCr-Raspberry/dp/B009FA2UYK/ref=sr_1_2) WiFi stick.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with `hostapd` and a edimax wifi stick, the sollution was to install the Realtek version of `hostapd`:

1. Disconnect the wifi stick and run `tail -f /var/log/syslog`.
2. Plug in the stick, you should see something like the following:
   `Using interface wlan0/xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx with driver <rtl8188cus>`
3. Note the driver name: `rtl8188cus`. *It could be different in your case.*
4. Go to the Realtek [software page](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true) and download the linux package for the above mentioned driver.
5. Unpack the .zip file and `cd` to `RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/wpa_supplicant_hostapd/wpa_supplicant_hostapd-0.8_rtw_r7475.20130812/hostapd`
6. Backup the original `hostapd`: `sudo mv /usr/sbin/hostapd /usr/sbin/hostapd.orig`
7. Build and install the Realtek version of `hostapd`:

   - `make all`
   - `sudo make install`
   - `sudo cp /usr/local/bin/hostapd /usr/sbin/`
8. Restart the `hostapd` service: `sudo service hostapd restart`